# php-gds datastore API v1 Fatal error: Class 'google\appengine\datastore\v4\RunQueryRequest' not found

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using [datastore-api-v1](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/tree/datastore-api-v1).

Here is my sample code:

```
    $obj_gateway = new GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf("Test123");

    $obj_schema = (new GDS\Schema("Messages"))
        ->addString('message_id')
        ->addString('type')
        ->addString('action')
        ->addInteger('to')
        ->addDatetime('created_at')
        ->addString('status')
        ->addString('message', FALSE);

    $obj_store = new GDS\Store($obj_schema,$obj_gateway);


    $query = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE `to` = 1 ORDER BY created_at";
    $obj_store->query($query);
    $arr_page = $obj_store->fetchPage(10, 0);
```

This is the error:

`Fatal error: Class 'google\appengine\datastore\v4\RunQueryRequest' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/csfiles/third_party/gds/vendor/tomwalder/php-gds/src/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php on line 164`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this, I have answered it on GitHub here

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/issues/134#issuecomment-247261645

ProtoBuf is for AppEngine environments only.
Use RESTv1 in non-AppEngine environments.

Cheers!